# Python Web data fetching: always the same time point

Tags: python

I wrote a script fetching price data from [here](http://www.gold.org/). The web page updates every minute.

However, whenever I run this script I get the same result: (1173.4, '2015-06-26 13:16:02'). It feels like I'm fetching the data from the same web page in a particular moment.

My environment is Win7 x64 with Anaconda(spider).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

def fetchPrice():
    req = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.gold.org/')
    page = req.read()
    req.close()
    websoup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    soup = websoup.findAll('div',attrs = {"class":"asset ask"})[0]
    plain = soup.findAll('dd',attrs = {"class":"value"})[0].text
    askprice = float(re.sub('[^0-9z\.]','',plain))
    t = websoup.findAll('span',attrs = {"class":"timestamp"})[0].text  
    return (askprice,t)

print(fetchPrice())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://www.gold.org/'

response = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
a = soup.findAll('div',attrs = {"class":"asset ask"})[0]
plain = soup.findAll('dd',attrs = {"class":"value"})[0].text
askprice = float(re.sub('[^0-9z\.]','',plain))
t = soup.findAll('span',attrs = {"class":"timestamp"})[0].text  
print askprice,t
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `re` module and you're overly complicating some parts of your parsing. See below code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as rq

def fetch_ask_price():

    # Prepare the soup.
    url = "http://www.gold.org"
    r = rq.get(url)
    soup = bsoup(r.content)

    # Get the ask price.
    ask_div = soup.find_all("div", class_="asset ask")[0]
    ask_dd = ask_div.find_all("dd", class_="value")[0]
    ask_price = ask_dd.get_text()

    # Get the timestamp.
    timestamp = soup.find_all("span", class_="timestamp")
    timestamp = timestamp[0].get_text()

    print timestamp, ask_price

fetch_ask_price()
```

Another variation below, using CSS selectors.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as rq

def fetch_ask_price():

    # Prepare the soup.
    url = "http://www.gold.org"
    r = rq.get(url)
    soup = bsoup(r.content)

    # Get the ask price.
    ask_div = soup.select("div.ask")[0]
    ask_dd = ask_div.select("dd.value")[0]
    ask_price = ask_dd.get_text()

    # Get the timestamp.
    timestamp = soup.select("span.timestamp")
    timestamp = timestamp[0].get_text()

    print timestamp, ask_price

fetch_ask_price()
```

Comment: That's really helpful for me to improve my codes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't update every minute. Rewriting the code won't change that - and none of the code suggestions make an iota of difference.

Comment: I checked the page source and you are right that the script doesn't update every minutes. Do you know how can we fetch realtime data like this?

Comment: What you are doing is probably as good as you are going to get - unless you find a website and which updates more regularly. I'm no expert - but stock exchanges possibly calculate the price based on buying and selling patterns of gold bonds. Websites that provide 'live' prices might then query APIs provided by stock exchanges. Without a better knowledge of those systems you or I couldn't know just how often they receive a new price.